# I need to know if I am using getline correctly

Tags: c, getline

I am using the getline() function in C and it keeps giving me seg faults when I use it more that once, as in for an array. Here is how I've written it:

```
temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*clen); 
read = getline(&temp, &clen, stdin);
tn = strtok(temp, ",");
strcpy(travel[tripnum].name, tn);
tn = strtok(NULL, ",");
travel[tripnum].country = tn;
free((void *) temp);
```

Please let me know if I am declaring something incorrectly

Comment: C doesn't have a `getline` function. Whose `getline` function are you trying to use?

Comment: It doesn't ? [What about this?](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html)

Comment: @fnokke: That `getline` is a GNU extension, which is fine but the question is only marked "C" which is why I asked the question. From the man page: "Both getline() and getdelim() are GNU extensions. They are available since libc 4.6.27."

Comment: If you use `getline()` more than once you don't show it. Post the full code (a reduced compilable version that exhibits the seg fault). And get rid of the casts.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in [this getline tutorial](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html) you need to allocate (clen + 1). One extra for the terminal NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing this
temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*clen+1);

Because of a null terminated string

Answer (score 0):

Try using this along with what others have told.
I feel in getline function clen should be used without the ampersand.
Like read = getline(&temp, clen, stdin);

Answer (score 0):

Your `tn` variable (result of `strtok()`) points inside the `temp` buffer.

The `temp` buffer is destroyed in the last line of your snippet, however one of the `tn` pointers (to the inside of `temp`) has been saved in `travel[tripnum].country`.

This `travel[tripnum].country` is a dangling pointer and all accesses through it are invalid.